# C++ split integer array into chunks

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, parallel-processing, mpi

I guess my question has 2 parts:

(1) Is this the right approach to send different chunks of an array to different processors?
Let's say I have `n` processors whose rank ranges from `0` to `n-1`.
I have an array of size `d`. I want to split this array into `k` equally-sized chunks. Assume `d` is divisible by `k`.
I want to send each of these chunks to a processor whose rank is less than `k`.
It would be easy if I can use something like MPI_Scatter, but this function sends to EVERY OTHER processors, and I only want to send to a certain number of procs.
So what I did was that I have a loop of `k` iterations and do `k` `MPI_Isend`'s.
Is this efficient?

(2) If it is, how do I split an array into chunks? There's always the easy way, which is

```
int size = d/k;
int buffs[k][size];

for (int rank = 0; rank < k; ++rank)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size ++i)
      buffs[rank][i] = input[rank*size + i];
    MPI_Isend(&buffs[rank], size, MPI_INT, rank, 1, comm, &request);
}
```

Comment: Won't this overwrite `buff` every time through your inner loop? Why not just send pointers to the original array?

Comment: My second question still stands; why are you bothering with the copy?

Comment: Good question! That's part of my first part of the question too! I was asking if what I did was the right approach.... seems like it wasn't.

Comment: Well actually you can't send the pointer because these are across processor! they don't have the same memory.

Comment: Why don't they have the same memory? Isn't that the whole point of SMP?

Comment: @CarlNorum, the question concerns MPI which is all about **interprocess** data exchange. When it comes to shared memory and threads, one typically uses OpenMP and not MPI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is `MPI_Scatterv` which allows you to explicitly specify the length of each chunk and its position relative to the beginning of the buffer. If you don't want to send data to certain ranks, simply set the length of their chunks to 0:

```
int blen[n];
MPI_Aint displ[n];

for (int rank = 0; rank < n; rank++)
{
    blen[rank] = (rank < k) ? size : 0;
    displ[rank] = rank * size;
}

int myrank;
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myrank);

MPI_Scatterv(input, blen, displ, MPI_INT,
             mybuf, myrank < k ? size : 0, MPI_INT,
             0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Note that for `rank >= k` the displacements will run past the end of the buffer. That is all right since block lengths are set to zero for `rank >= k` and no data will be accessed.

As for your original approach, it is not portable and might not always work. The reason is that you are overwriting the same `request` handle and you never wait for the sends to complete. The correct implementation is:

```
MPI_Request request[k];

for (int rank = 0; rank < k; ++rank)
{
    MPI_Isend(&input[rank*size], size, MPI_INT, rank, 1, comm, &request[rank]);
}
MPI_Waitall(k, request, MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE);
```

The most optimal implementation would be to use `MPI_Scatter` in a subcommunicator:

```
MPI_Comm subcomm;
MPI_Comm_split(MPI_COMM_WORLD, myrank < k ? 0 : MPI_UNDEFINED, myrank,
               &subcomm);
// Now there are k ranks in subcomm
// Perform the scatter in the subcommunicator
if (subcomm != MPI_COMM_NULL)
   MPI_Scatter(input, size, MPI_INT, mybuf, size, MPI_INT, 0, subcomm);
```

The `MPI_Comm_split` call splits `MPI_COMM_WORLD` and creates a new communicator from all original ranks less than `k`. It uses the original rank as key for ordering the ranks in the new communicator, therefore rank 0 in `MPI_COMM_WORLD` becomes rank 0 in `subcomm`. Since `MPI_Scatter` often performs better than `MPI_Scatterv`, this one is the most optimal solution.